# EOFError, what happen to my minitest selenium test? how to fix it?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, minitest, capybara-webkit

After my ubuntu updates, my minitest selenium test got an error, saying:

```
EOFError:         EOFError: end of file reached
```

**and it opens many blank google chrome windows as feature test total count**.

my Ubuntu 16.04 updates was (**yesterday everything works fine until the system made an update**):

```
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.105'
Upgrade: snap-confine:amd64 (1.0.42-0ubuntu3~16.04.1, 1.0.43-0ubuntu1~16.04.1), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (53.0.2785.143-1, 54.0.2840.59-1), ubuntu-core-launcher:amd64 (1.0.42-0ubuntu3~16.04.1, 1.0.43-0ubuntu1~16.04.1), libtracker-sparql-1.0-0:amd64 (1.6.2-0ubuntu1, 1.6.2-0ubuntu1.1)
```

in my **test_helper.rb**, I have:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
```

I tried to uninstall Google Chrome and used **Chromium browser and it works fine.** 
**I wanna know how to do it with Google Chrome browser.**

Do somebody knows how to fix it?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is going to help, but I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138010/capybara-selenium-xvfb-throwing-end-of-file-error-after-recent-update-of-ubuntu) and was able to determine that I was using a gem called [chromedriver-helper](https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper). That readme said to try running `chromedriver-update` within the rails app and that cleared everything up.

Comment: YES it works, thank you very much :)
Good thing we encounter the same problem :)