# Capybara selenium xvfb throwing end of file error after recent update of Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: selenium, capybara, eof, ubuntu-16.04

Currently in my Ruby on Rails application cucumber test are being run with the [capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) gem and using selenium.

Recently after a system update to Ubuntu 16.04 the tests started failing with `EOFError: end of file reached` errors

Additionally, it also occasionally includes the following error.

```
session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData": "frameId":"14314.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
(Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.59)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371461 (633e689b520b25f3e264a2ede6b74ccc23cb636a),platform=Linux 4.4.0-43-generic x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011762/eoferror-what-happen-to-my-minitest-selenium-test-how-to-fix-it) also refers to something similar but with minitest.

This what I believe to be the relevant part of the capybara `env.rb` file:

```
require 'cucumber/rails'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'capybara-screenshot'
require 'capybara-screenshot/cucumber'
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'minitest/rails'
require 'mocha/mini_test'
require 'headless'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'rack_session_access/capybara'
require 'webmock/cucumber'
WebMock.allow_net_connect!
include Sprig::Helpers

ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false
Dir.mkdir('test_result') unless File.exist?('test_result')
# Remove/comment out the lines below if your app doesn't have a database.
# For some databases (like MongoDB and CouchDB) you may need to use :truncation instead.
begin
 DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, { only: [] }
 DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation, { only: [] }  

rescue NameError
  raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
end

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
  client.timeout = 15
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, http_client: client)
end

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
Capybara.raise_server_errors = true
Capybara.default_selector = :css
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 15
Capybara.save_and_open_page_path = 'tmp/capybara'
```

I've looked over at a [thread in the capybara-webkit gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/782) that looks related, but I'm not actually using webkit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Upgrade your chromedriver to the latest release - 2.24

Comment: @TomWalpole That led me down the right path. I made an edit to the original post. Thanks for your help, I was going crazy.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I'm using a gem called [chromedriver-helper](https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper) that was using rbenv to override the version of chromedriver that was actually being used by capybara and selenium to run the tests. The gem readme said to try running `chromedriver-update` in the context of the rails app, which cleared everything up.

Comment: life saver, still don't understand where the problem came from out of nowhere